# SQL Query to Fetch Two Records Per Each ID

Tags: sql, oracle

lets suppose i have this table

```
ID  CLASS
1   A
1   A
1   A
2   A
2   B
2   B
3   C
4   C
```

how to fetch two random records per each ID using Oracle SQL

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT id, 
                    class, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.NORMAL ) rn
             FROM test)
SELECT id, class
FROM cte 
WHERE rn <= 2
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4372dc17415ba83dbcbe3e71ae5f04f0)

Comment: I don't think I would use a normal distribution for this, but it doesn't make a difference.  This is the right approach.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nothing prevents to use any another random sorting, including one with another distribution... I took the first one that came across in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t (ID, CLASS) as (
select 1 , 'A' from dual union all
select 1 , 'A' from dual union all 
select 1 , 'A' from dual union all 
select 2 , 'A' from dual union all 
select 2 , 'B' from dual union all 
select 2 , 'B' from dual union all 
select 3 , 'C' from dual union all 
select 4 , 'C' from dual 
)
select * from (
select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by null) rn from t 
)
where rn <= 2
;
```

unless you specify some ordering, oracle will return rows in a random manner by default.

Comment: *unless you specify some ordering, oracle will return rows in a random manner by default.* That is theory only. In practice - 10 executions, 10 times `(2,'A'),(2,'B')` and zero times `(2,'B'),(2,'B')` was returned...

Comment: @Slkrasnodar . . . The ordering is not RANDOM.  It is INDETERMINATE.  It can change at the whim of Oracle or anything else.  An `ORDER BY` is needed to ensure the ordering is as desired.